# Use libdvbpsi on Android app to get EPG information

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc, c-libraries, epg

I'm developing an app to run on a set top box with Android. This app has a media player to play multicast IPTV streams. I use LibVLC and VLCVideoLayout, following the official [java_sample](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples). I want to get EPG information and it seems that [libdvbpsi](https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvbpsi.html) does this work. But it is a C library and I don't know how can I import it to my Android app.

I found this [libdvbpsi for android](https://github.com/xugaoxiang/libdvbpsiForAndroid) library but I don't understand how to use it.

My development environment:

- Windows 10 Pro.
- Android Studio 4.1.2.

So how can use libdvbpsi on Android app?

Comment: dvbpsi seems enabled in vlc-android already. Can you find the info you're looking for when playing your stream with the official VLC android app?

Comment: I installed VLC 3.3.4, added an UDP address and the app displays program name. I downloaded the code from https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android and searched for eit and epg, but I didn't find anything.